# Python dict of dicts with default value

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, default-value

In python 2.7 I've got a dictionary of dictionaries, and I'm trying to get values from this in a speedy way. However, sometimes one of the keys (could be either one) doesn't exist in my dictionary, in that case I would like to get a default value.

My dictionary looks like this:

```
values = { '1A' : { '2A' : 'valAA', '2B' : 'valAB'},
           '1B' : { '2A' : 'valBA', '2B' : 'valBB'} }
```

which works great when I query it with existing keys:

```
>>> values['1A']['2A']
'valAA'
>>> values.get('1B').get('2B')
'valBB'
```

How do I get it to do this:

```
>>> values.get('not a key').get('not a key')
'not present'
```

Comment: Sorry, missed that one, thought I figured out something new but it's a duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works like a charm:

```
values.get(key1, {}).get(key2, defaultValue)
```

In case the second key is not present in the dictionary, the default value of the second `.get()` is returned.
In case the first key is not present in the dictionary, the default value is an empty dictionary, which ensures the second key will not be present in it. The default value for the second `.get()` will then be returned as well.

For example:

```
>>> defaultValue = 'these are not the values you are looking for'
>>> key1, key2 = '1C', '2C'
>>> values.get(key1, {}).get(key2, defaultValue)
'these are not the values you are looking for'
>>> key1, key2 = '1A', '2B'
>>> values.get(key1, {}).get(key2, defaultValue)
'valAB'
```

Comment: This won't work if you try key2 first

Comment: @RafaelCardoso: why would you try key2 first? This works just fine.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I've seen no guarantee you know which key comes first. Maybe in this specific example where keys are "ordered", but it is certainly not a generic solution.

Comment: @RafaelCardoso: but `key1` is applied to the outer dictionary, `key2` to the inner. There is an order here. I'm not sure what you are getting at.

Comment: I've just read it again and you're correct. Not sure where the hell I took that from lol

Answer (score 1):

Create a function to the get the value.

```
values = { '1A' : { '2A' : 'valAA', '2B' : 'valAB'},
           '1B' : { '2A' : 'valBA', '2B' : 'valBB'} }

def get_value(dict, k1, k2):
    try:
        return dict[k1][k2]
    except KeyError as ex:
        return 'does not exist'

print get_value(values, '1A', '2A')
print get_value(values, '1A', '4A')
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion